# How do you save value of response from xml webservice to session in Laravel?

Tags: xml, laravel, guzzle

I am using `Guzzle` api to connect to my xml web service.
I am able to receive response and also display on my web browser the response data.

```
    $response = $client->post('http:www.xmlwebservice.com',['body'=>$request]);
    $result = $response->getBody()->getContents();
    $result1 = simplexml_load_string($result);
    $Id = $result1["Id"];
```

Now I want store the Id sent from webservice to my session using
Session::put("SessionId",$Id);

But it shows error saying:

`"Serialization of 'SimpleXMLElement' is not allowed"`
Can anyone help me store

Answer (score 0):

You could use this package to handle converting the xml to an array:

https://github.com/mtownsend5512/xml-to-array

```
$result1 = collect(xml_to_array($result));
```

Now you have a collection with all your data and you can put it in a session.